# Validates data of other model when accepts_nested_attributes_for is used

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-4, rails-activerecord

I have belongs to and has many relation.

The problem is that I need to check if score field from nested attributes is less 0, it should not save records instead return to form with error message.

The code I am trying is:

```
class QuizAttempt < ActiveRecord::Base

  has_many :quiz_answers
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :quiz_answers, reject_if: :invalid_score

  validate :score_greater_than_zero

  private

  def score_greater_than_zero
    errors.add(:quiz_answers, 'must greater than 0') if invalid_score(attributes)
  end

  def invalid_score(attributes)
    attributes['score'].to_i > 0
  end
end


class QuizAnswer < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :quiz_attempt
end
```

The form field looks like that containing array:

```
name="quiz_attempt[quiz_answers_attributes][5][score]"
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I need to check if `score` field from nested attributes is less 0

What you need is access nested objects (`quiz_answers`) and check their attributes, not `quiz_attempt`'s attributes:

```
  def score_greater_than_zero
    if quiz_answers.any? { |answer| answer.score <= 0 }
      errors.add(:quiz_answers, 'must be greater than 0')
    end
  end
```

Comment: In this case the reason of using `reject_if` is also baseless?

Comment: @LearningROR `reject_if` is something else, it will just not save the nested object if the condition is satisfied, whereas custom validation will fire validation error and must rerender the form. So these are a bit different things

Comment: @LearningROR can't guess why, any hints/stacktrace? :)

Comment: @LearningROR debug it. add `binding.pry` as the first line of the method and check it step by step..

Comment: Sorry, it still submits the form. I tried using it like: `if @quiz_attempt.update_score
          flash[:notice] = 'Quiz saved Successfully!'
        else
          flash[:error] = @quiz_attempt.errors.full_messages.join
        end`

Comment: @LearningROR I am pretty sure I wrote it correctly. Check if your `score` is integer and if it is indeed being saved as **less than 0**. Just sanity check everything

Comment: I am trying to submit `0.0` and the datatype is: `score double precision DEFAULT 0.0`

Comment: @LearningROR `0.0` is not less than `0` :) Change the validation to `<= 0` and you'll get error message. As I say, always sanity check things ;)

Comment: @LearningROR hehe :)